# Convert Dataframe to muti-index datafram pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing dataframe which contains Country , Weather , Temp, Date extracted from CSV file.
I would like to convert the dataframe to muti-index and export out to excel file

```
df = pd.read_csv('Country.csv')

df
Out[47]: 
     Country Weather  Temp      Date
0      Korea   Sunny    30  20201201
1      Japan  Rainny    26  20201201
2    England   Sunny    27  20201201
3   Malaysia  Rainny    25  20201201
4      Korea   Sunny    30  20201202
5      Japan  Rainny    26  20201202
6    England   Sunny    27  20201202
7   Malaysia  Rainny    25  20201202
8      Korea  Rainny    30  20201203
9      Japan  Rainny    26  20201203
10   England  Rainny    27  20201203
11  Malaysia  Rainny    28  20201203
```

I had tried using `df.set_index(['Country', 'Date'])` but it is not working

output version

[image]

Comment: Try: `df=df.set_index(['Country', 'Date'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.set_index(['Country', 'Date']).unstack(1).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Date     20201201         20201202         20201203        
             Temp Weather     Temp Weather     Temp Weather
Country                                                    
England        27   Sunny       27   Sunny       27  Rainny
Japan          26  Rainny       26  Rainny       26  Rainny
Korea          30   Sunny       30   Sunny       30  Rainny
Malaysia       25  Rainny       25  Rainny       28  Rainny
```

Comment: I was trying to make this work with `pivot_table` but it didn't want to aggregate the 'Weather' column even after changing it to a categorical dtype.

Comment: @wwii `df.pivot('Country', 'Date', ['Weather', 'Temp'] ).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`

Comment: @wwii Yeah, pivot_table isn't going to work in a single step, because, pivot_table only accepts a single "value" column and not a list of value columns.